# Application.Current.Shutdown() c# app is not closing properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

I have a c# app normally `Application.Current.Shutdown()` closes the app successfully. But when a create a new thread inside app and then closing, app is not closed properly. Inside task manager app is showing after closing under background tasks. Why is this happening?. How to kill all threads associated with my app while closing?

```
public void ButtonClose(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

`Thread Launch = new Thread(() => Job(id,name));Launch.Start();`

**EDIT**
app name is shown in task manager under apps category. If I close app before starting thread then app name is removed from task manager. If I close app after starting thread then app name is removed from apps category and shown in background processes category.

Comment: Is that a background thread or foreground thread. If foreground then application insance will remain unitl thread is compete

Comment: @neeleshbodgal `Thread Launch = new Thread(() => Job(id,name));Launch.Start();` this is how a started a thread

Comment: You need to mark the thread as being a background thread, set the `IsBackground` property on the thread to `true` before starting it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: can you try setting this property Launch.IsBackground = true; and check

Comment: Note that flagging the thread as a background thread will terminate the thread when you ask the program to terminate. You will need some proper try/catch handling in the thread code to terminate the thread in an orderly fashion, if that is necessary.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal @Lassev.karlsen  I tried `.IsBackground =tre;` But still after closing app. task manager shows app name inside background processes

Comment: Can you update before and after closing app, screenshots of task manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was `System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();` was not terminating my threads. I found that `Thread.Abort()` method can abort the threads, I changed my code to

```
private Thread Launch;
public void ButtonClose(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Launch.Abort();
            Logger.Info("Thread aborted");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Exception inside close --> " + ex.Message);
        }
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

`Launch = new Thread(() => Job(id, name));
 Launch.IsBackground = true;
 Launch.Start();`
Now its works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Tasks instead of Threads if you have no specific reason to prefer Threads. Tasks are managed differently and usually executed on a threadpool which is why they produce less overhead. Also you can make more mistakes with Threads than with Tasks.

Tasks will automatically end when you close your application. You can start a Task like this:

```
Task.Run(()=>
{
    //This code is executed in another task (asynchronously)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The application cannot finish until all its threads finish, when you close the window you only close the main thread that handles the interface but the thread keeps it alive I recommend something like this.

```
private System.Threading.Thread thread;
private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource token = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();

//starting Thread
thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart((obj) =>
{
while (true && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    //long running operation
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
} }));
thread.Start();

//on main window
window.Closed += (obj, args) =>
{
    token.Cancel();
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
};
```